# Google Chat bot to auto expand ticket references

Tags: google-hangouts

In Chat, we often refer to specific issues in our ticketing system.

Ideally I'd like to create a bot that would automatically convert a ticket reference (RM#xxxx) to a hyperlink, possibly also looking up the ticket subject and inserting it too.

My understanding is that this is not possible as a bot must be invoked by an @ mention.

Is there any way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Do you need to achieve it in a public chat room, or can it be a private conversation between the user and the bot?

Comment: Public chat room - human A might speak to human B about ticket RM#xxxx. Bot auto expands RM#xxxx to a link to the ticket URL.

Comment: In the documentation there is explicitly stated that you need to mention the bot so it can read the message. Is that a problem for you?